# Is this Orbit Sprinkler Timer (Model 57894) compatible with Rainbird Valve(s)?

Tags: valve, sprinkler-system, timer

I recently purchased an Orbit Model # 57894, and I'm trying to use it with these [Rainbird Valves](http://www.lowes.com/pd_29196-147-DAS-075/ASVF_0__?k_clickID=b8f433bb-488b-4d5f-8ef9-2d6c0f8b627c&store_code=1971&productId=3133713&selectedLocalStoreBeanArray=%5Bcom.lowes.commerce.storelocator.beans.LocatorStoreBean%4022a922a9%5D&storeNumber=1971&kpid=3133713&cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-_-RoughPlumbingElectrical-_-UndergroundIrrigation-_-3133713%3ARain_Bird&CAWELAID=&CAWELAID=1367969395).

I've got it all setup and connected, however it won't turn on the sprinklers on schedule or on manual mode. Are these valves incompatible with this timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the Timer and the Valves are designed for 24 VAC operation which is the standard voltage for sprinkler equipment so they should be compatible. You need to check with a voltmeter that the Timer is outputting the proper voltage and that it is present at the valves.